# php uploading a file says it is working but does not actually upload a file

Tags: php

I have a website that i would like to upload a file to a temp directory. For some reason the code that i am using is saying that the file is uploaded, but it is not actually uploaded to that directory when i check. I have write permissions on for all users and am still having no luck...

Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
    <p align="center"><input type="file" name="file" size="60"></p>
    <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></p>
</form>
```

Here is my upload.php file:

```
<?php
    $folder = '/tmp';
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            echo 'File uploaded';
        } else {
            echo 'File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions';
        };
    } else {
        echo 'File is not uploaded.';
    }; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to upload a file to your local folder instead of tmp.

This should fix it:

Change `$folder = '/tmp';` to `$folder = '/tmp/';`

Comment: That was it. Coincidentally, i figured this out just before I was checking the page again. I will upvote this when SO lets me.