# PHP: File is uploaded but it does not get moved from the temporary directory. How do I resolve it?

Tags: php, file-io

I am trying to upload an image to server (I am using Google Cloud Virtual Machine) that the PHP gets from a Python script (I intend to retrieve the images from a Raspberry Pi camera sensor, but for now, I am sending a placeholder image to test the functionality of my script) that sends the image along with other parameters through a POST request. However, while the image does get uploaded, it does not get moved to a new location as it is shown in the Output I have provided below along with the code.

A question found here: [php uploading a file says it is working but does not actually upload a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945743/php-uploading-a-file-says-it-is-working-but-does-not-actually-upload-a-file) does have a similar problem, however the suggested solution there did not help me.

Here's the code that implements the file upload system.

PHP Upload File code:

```
    //Upload the image   
    $uploadDir = "/home/username/directory/";
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES["myimage"]["name"]);

    if(is_uploaded_file["myimage"]["tmp_name"]) 
    {
        echo "File has been UPLOADED\n";                          
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myimage"]["tmp_name"],$uploadFile))      
        {      
            echo "File has been MOVED";
        } 
        else     
        {       
             echo "File has NOT been MOVED";
        }
    }     
    else     
    {               
        echo "File has NOT been UPLOADED";
    }
```

Python code which sends a request to the PHP above:

```
    import requests

    def postData(directory):
        activity = "Someone walked in"
        url = 'http://35.198.114.146/index.php/sensor_readings/postdata?activity=' + activity
        image = {'myimage': open(imagePath,'rb')}

        r = requests.post(url,files=image)
        print(r.text)

    imagePath = 'cam_images/test.png'
    postData(imagePath)
```

Output:

```
    File has been UPLOADED
    File has NOT been MOVED
```

I have been stuck on this problem for weeks and I am not sure on what to do. Any kind of help is appreciated. Should you need more details or code, feel free to ask me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please modify the code with this line:

`echo "File has been UPLOADED " . print_r($_FILES,true) . "\n";`

and share the output

Comment: You probably don't have permissions to write to that directory. Try changing your `$uploadDir` to something like `/tmp` to test this out.

Comment: Or test with `is_writable($uploadDir)`

Comment: @PaulRM this is the output that it has given me:

        `Array
        (
            [myimage] => Array
            (
                [name] => test.jpg
                [type] => 
                [tmp_name] => /opt/bitnami/php/tmp/phpxdpsBH
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 32094
            )
        )`

Comment: @miken32 it turns out that the directory was not writable as tested with `is_writable($uploadDir)` . What is interesting is that I ran `sudo chmod 755` on the directory, but I can give it another shot

Comment: It's not just the one directory. The user running PHP must have permissions to traverse directories above as well. And you must be watching out for systems like SELinux which might be preventing a write as well.

Comment: So, I ran `sudo chmod -R a+rwx` on the directory and it works perfectly now. I can move the files there. Thank you very much, @miken32, I will put you down as a reference. And thanks to everyone else who replied too

Comment: That's not very safe at all...

Comment: It's for the assignment, this will be shut down once we are done :)

Comment: But what is the safe way of doing it, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Hey @terasss2, I think that I found the problem, you are trying to move: 
`$_FILES["myimage"]["tmp_name"]` 
and maybe it will be: 
`$_FILES["myimage"]["name"]`